# Why is my Canon dRebel not syncing with my off-camera flash when using a camera-to-remote cable?

Tags: canon, flash, troubleshooting, off-camera-flash, sync

UPDATE:
Thanks to all who pointed out my folly. The shutter trigger port is NOT the flash trigger port. Even though it sorta works :(

---

Using a Canon EOS T3 with Neewer NW-625 speedlight kit with the FC-16 radio trigger. When the trigger remote is connected to the hotshoe on camera, it fires in sync with the shutter perfectly. But when I connect with the 3.5mm to 6.35mm connector cable, it's out of sync. I can't tell if the remote is slower or faster.

So if I also want to use on-camera flash, they are out of sync. Both flashes fire, but not at the same time, apparently.

Any experience with this issue? Yes, it's an older camera but wtf...

Do I need to manually sync the flashes? Is there a documented way to do that?

Comment: There is no cable connection for flash sync on the T3. What are you connecting the trigger cable to?

Comment: It looks like you're connecting the trigger with the remote control terminal on your camera. That's not for radio triggers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm making an educated guess that the FC-16 triggers you have are rebranded 2.4 MHz [Godox FC-16](http://www.godox.com/EN/InstructionManual/Godox_FC16_20171008.pdf) triggers, since that's what I see packaged with your speedlight model (which is not a rebranded Godox speedlight) on Amazon.

No speedlight uses a 6.5mm connector. So, I assume a studio strobe/monolight is being used, here. **You've probably got the cable plugged into the wrong 3.5mm port on the receiver and/or a switch on the trigger is set incorrectly**.

The main confusion here is that these triggers can do double duty as either flash triggers, or remote shutter release. And the shutter release can be set to use a delay which would throw off flash sync.

**If you're attempting to cable the strobe to the 3.5mm port on the side of the T3**, that won't work. That's not a flash sync port.  Canon only uses [PC (Protor-Compur) connectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prontor-Compur) for flash sync on their cameras. The 3.5mm port on the dRebel models is for a cable release to trip the shutter of the camera.

**If you're attempting to cable the strobe to the receiver** (Rx) FC-16 unit, then you need to make sure you use the flash port and that the switch is set to flash mode, so it knows which port to use.  Do not use the camera port, or use the flash port with the switch set to camera or vice versa.

**If you're attempting to cable the strobe directly to the transmitter** (Tx), you need to make sure that the switch is set for flash, not camera, or delay.

Comment: you guys are awesome and that certainly explains it very well. Thank you! I now know that just because the plug fits the receiver doesn't mean it should :)

Comment: @JohnO'Keefe yeah, that and that standardization is **not** the strength of most camera companies. :D

Answer (score 4):

[image: Canon T3 manual]

As you can see, the port you are probably using, is an input port for a wired remote control, not an output port for flash sync.

You may make it work, if you connect one flash onto the hotshoe and set the other flashes on optical triggering if they support that.

Comment: makes perfect sense. I will see about the optical trigger. thanks!